# Chrome Search within a page arrow keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome

I often search for a particular word on a webpage using Google Chrome. On my Mac, I do Command + F to bring search on a page window. To go to the next occurrence of the word I use the up or down arrows. Are there keyboard shortcuts for using these arrows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the keyboard to move to the next and previous search result:

**Next:** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Previous:** <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

For Windows users, replace <kbd>Cmd</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

source: [keyboard shortcuts on Chrome Help online](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179)